# Create a fragment for a select multiple element in thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

I'm trying to create a fragment for the multiselect field in my webapp. But I'm running into various issues with regards to passing in the field that should be bound to the select element. I figure I have a syntax error, but I'm not sure what it is.

For selectedField in my addUser.jsp file, I've tried `${selectedAdminAccess}`, `*{selectedAdminAccess}`, `${userForm.selectedAdminAccess}`, etc.

And with those various combinations, in the forms.html file, I've tried  `${selectField}`, `*{selectField}`, and the preprocessor directive: `${__${selectField}__}`. Have I just missed the correct combination?

The error I'm getting is "Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'X' available as request attribute". Where X is (for the preprocessor attempt) the fieldname entered in the addUser.jsp page, or "selectField" when not using the preprocessor attempt.

Here's what I've got.

Controller

```
@GetMapping(value={"/adduser"}
public ModelAndView getAddUserPage(Model model, @RequstParam(required = false) Long selectedUserId) {

   ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("/addUser");
   UserForm userForm = new UserForm();
   mav.addObject("userForm", userForm);
   return mav;
}
```

model UserForm

```
public class UserForm {
    private List<Office> adminAccess = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> selectedAdminAccess = new ArrayList<>();
// Getter/Setter 
...
}
```

addUser.jsp

```
<form method="post" action="#" data-th-action="@{/addUser}" data-th-object="${userForm}">
   <!-- other interesting page stuff -->
   <div data-th-replace="fragments/forms.html :: multi-select(
      id='adminSelect',
      selectClass='office-target',
      selectField='*{selectedAdminAccess}',
      optionList='*{adminAccess}',
      optionListValue='id',
      optionListText='name',
      size=8)"></div>
</form>
```

forms.html

```
<div data-th-fragment="multi-select(id, selectClass, selectField, optionList, optionListValue, optionListText, size)" >
    <select id="${id}" class="mdb-select colorful-select md-form ${selectClass}" size="${size}" multiple
            searchable data-th-field="${__${selectField}__}">
        <option data-th-each="option : ${adminAccess}"
                data-th-value="${option.__${optionListValue}__}"
                data-th-text="${option.__${optionListText}__}"></option>
    </select>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ultimate goal here is to have an expression `data-th-field="*{selectedAdminAccess}"` To accomplish this:

- For `selectField`, you need to pass a string with value `'selectedAdminAccess'`.
- For `th:field`, use the preprocessing expression `*{__${selectField}__}`.

The HTML you provided looks like it has other problems... but I think your final HTML will look something like this:

```
<!-- page -->
<form method="post" action="#" data-th-action="@{/addUser}" data-th-object="${userForm}">
  <!-- other interesting page stuff -->
  <div data-th-replace="fragments/forms.html :: multi-select(
    id='adminSelect',
    selectClass='office-target',
    selectField='selectedAdminAccess',
    optionList=*{adminAccess},
    optionListValue='id',
    optionListText='name',
    size=8
  )" />
</form>

<!-- fragment -->
<div data-th-fragment="multi-select(id, selectClass, selectField, optionList, optionListValue, optionListText, size)" >
    <select data-th-id="${id}"
            data-th-class="|mdb-select colorful-select md-form ${selectClass}|"
            data-th-size="${size}"
            multiple
            searchable
            data-th-field="*{__${selectField}__}">
        <option data-th-each="option : ${optionList}"
                data-th-value="${option.optionListValue}"
                data-th-text="${option.optionListText}" />
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: D'oh! I must have missed that combination. The `value` and the `text` probably need to stay as they are since it could be anything (name or description, based on the backing object). Also optionList should probably be `optionList='adminAccess'`. I'll give it a try on Monday.

Answer (score 0):

Using Metroids' answer above, here is the final solution that worked for me:

```
<!-- page -->
<form method="post" action="#" data-th-action="@{/addUser}" data-th-object="${userForm}">
  <!-- other interesting page stuff -->
  <div data-th-replace="fragments/forms.html :: multi-select(
    id='adminSelect',
    selectClass='office-target',
    selectField='selectedAdminAccess',
    optionList='adminAccess',
    optionListValue='id',
    optionListText='name',
    size=8
  )"></div>
</form>

<!-- fragment -->
<div data-th-fragment="multi-select(id, selectClass, selectField, optionList, optionListValue, optionListText, size)" >
    <select data-th-id="${id}"
            data-th-class="|mdb-select colorful-select md-form ${selectClass}|"
            data-th-size="${size}"
            multiple
            searchable
            data-th-field="*{__${selectField}__}">
        <option data-th-each="option : ${__${optionList}__}"
                data-th-value="${option.__${optionListValue}__}"
                data-th-text="${option.__${optionListText}__}" />
    </select>
</div>
```

The reason for the value and text to be the way they are is to allow a more dynamic object to be passed in. The text could be a name, description, or whatever. The value could be an id, or the text value, or whatever. That style I learned from https://www.northcoder.com/2019/11/thymeleaf-look-at-two-of-its-most.html and their github project linked on the page.

Crazy thing is, now that I see the answer, it was staring me in the face the whole time (it's how the value and text are being used.)